# Custom ordering (partitioning?) by two columns and paginating in one query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Let's say we have the following data:

```
+-----+------------+------------------+
| uid |  company   +   last_complaint |
+-----+------------+------------------+
|   1 |    Foo inc +       2015-01-01 |
|   2 |    Bar ltd +       2015-02-02 |
|   3 |    Baz inc +       2015-03-03 |
|   4 |    Bar ltd +       2015-04-04 |
|   5 |    Foo inc +       2015-05-05 |
+-----+------------+------------------+
```

I need to sort the records so that:

- newest records go first;
- if there are any more records (regardless of date) originating from the same company, they should go immediately after (also sorted by last complained date among them), followed by the next newest record and so on.

So the desired outcome would be as follows:

```
+-----+------------+------------------+
| uid |  company   +   last_complaint |
+-----+------------+------------------+
|   5 |    Foo inc +       2015-05-05 |
|   1 |    Foo inc +       2015-01-01 |
|   4 |    Bar ltd +       2015-04-04 |
|   2 |    Bar ltd +       2015-02-02 |
|   3 |    Baz inc +       2015-03-03 |
+-----+------------+------------------+
```

On top of this I might need to show the second page of such order (it's OK if the same company records split between pages).

It is obvious that `ORDER BY` simply isn't good enough and a better tool is necessary. I've looked at some queries which do partitioning, however I'm not sure if this concept can be successfully applied for this case.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick, where the subquery first orders the company column based on their last complaint and then returns the data from the main table based on that order:

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1
    (
      [uid] INT ,
      [company] VARCHAR(7) ,
      [last_complaint] DATETIME
    );

INSERT  INTO #Table1
        ( [uid], [company], [last_complaint] )
VALUES  ( 1, 'Foo inc', '2015-01-01 00:00:00' ),
        ( 2, 'Bar ltd', '2015-02-02 00:00:00' ),
        ( 3, 'Baz inc', '2015-03-03 00:00:00' ),
        ( 4, 'Bar ltd', '2015-04-04 00:00:00' ),
        ( 5, 'Foo inc', '2015-05-05 00:00:00' );

SELECT  #Table1.*
FROM    #Table1
        INNER JOIN ( SELECT company ,
                            ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY MAX(last_complaint) DESC ) rn
                     FROM   #Table1
                     GROUP BY company
                   ) t ON t.company = #Table1.company
ORDER BY rn ,
        last_complaint DESC

DROP TABLE #Table1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method using window functions to get the most recent complaint date for each company:

```
select d.*
from (select d.*,
             max(last_complaint) over (partition by company) as maxlc
      from data d
     ) d
order by maxlc desc, company, last_complaint desc;
```